# Shadow not working "Android"

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/am"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Admissions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"            
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:shadowDx="4"
        android:shadowDy="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code.. i am trying to give engraved effect to my text.. so i am applying white shadow to blue kindof color.. but there is no shadow effect.. tell me what to do..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing:

```
android:shadowRadius="5"
```

It doesn't work without radius.

Comment: It wrked.. i thought there is no need of it.. thnx